# Can't trigger POST-JSON request with d3 typings

Tags: d3.js, typescript

I am starting a new project using Typescript, from which I have no previous experience. I want to do some HTTP requests using [d3.xhr](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#post) method without much success so far. See below the related piece of code:

```
private buildBody(query: string): any {
  return {
    statements: [{
      statement: query
    }]
  }
}

exec(query: string) {
  d3.xhr(this.baseURL)
    .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .post(buildBody(query), (error, data) => {
      if (error){
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
}
```

This seems to be invalid. Having a look at the d3 types definition, there's something I don't really understand:

```
post: {
  /**
  * Issue the request using the POST method
  *
  * @param callback Function to invoke on completion of request
  */
  (callback?: (xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => void ): Xhr;
  /**
  * Issue the request using the POST method
  *
  * @param data Data to post back in the request
  * @param callback Function to invoke on completion of request
  */
  (data: any, callback?: (xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => void ): Xhr;
};
```

Post requests callbacks are expected to be of type `(xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => void` while d3 API expects some two-argument function. How are callbacks normally defined in Typescript? Is the post method (callback types) definition actually correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post: {
  /**
  * Issue the request using the POST method
  *
  * @param callback Function to invoke on completion of request
  */
  (callback?: (xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => void ): Xhr;
  /**
  * Issue the request using the POST method
  *
  * @param data Data to post back in the request
  * @param callback Function to invoke on completion of request
  */
  (data: any, callback?: (xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => void ): Xhr;
};
```

Is just a way of telling javascript that `post` is a function (*one* function) that can be called in two different ways.

For example:

```
foo: function(a, b) {

    if (b != null)
        return a * 2 + b;
    else
        return a * 2;
}
```

The `foo` function be called in two ways in javascript, e.g:

```
var a = foo(3);
var b = foo(3, 4);
```

Both of the above calls to foo are valid. To tell typescript that this is the case we can create a definition that includes this information:

```
foo: {
   (a: number): number;
   (a: number, b: number): number
}
```

So in the *post* case it is simply a way of saying that post has *a* method that can be called in more than one way.

This said, there might still be a problem with the definition being wrong compared with the api.

EDIT:

Ok so I looked in to the d3 [source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/xhr/xhr.js) and this is how it is defined:

```
// Convenience methods.
["get", "post"].forEach(
    function(method) {
        xhr[method] = function() {
            return xhr.send.apply(xhr, [method].concat(d3_array(arguments)));
        };
    });

// If callback is non-null, it will be used for error and load events.
xhr.send = function(method, data, callback) {
    if (arguments.length === 2 && typeof data === "function") callback = data, data = null;
    request.open(method, url, true);
    if (mimeType != null && !("accept" in headers)) headers["accept"] = mimeType + ",*/*";
    if (request.setRequestHeader) for (var name in headers) request.setRequestHeader(name, headers[name]);
    if (mimeType != null && request.overrideMimeType) request.overrideMimeType(mimeType);
    if (responseType != null) request.responseType = responseType;
    if (callback != null) xhr.on("error", callback).on("load", function(request) { callback(null, request); });
    dispatch.beforesend.call(xhr, request);
    request.send(data == null ? null : data);
    return xhr;
};
```

Given that it seems like the definition is just plainly wrong. The `callback` is called in two ways; `callback(null, request);` or `xhr.on("error", callback)`. In the case where the request is passed to the callback the request is of type `XMLHttpRequest`. But yeah the definition is wrong.

Comment: that's correct but not my question. My question is whether the callback type (`(xhr: XMLHttpRequest) => void`) is correct, because with such definition, I am not able to trigger any single request. I will update my question, making this clearer.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I created a PR, it seems the type definition was indeed wrong. I will accept your answer, thanks for your time.